# SAP RFC_READ_TABLE not returning all digits

Tags: saprfc

Using the RFC_READ_TABLE FM for the first time, I am trying to pull stock data from the table MARD. Some parts have unrestricted stock value (LABST) greater than 1 billion.  When viewing this table using SE16N, the full value is visible, but when pulling with RFC_READ_TABLE, the first few digits get truncated and replaced with a *.

For example, one material might have a value of 1,517,826,100.000 when viewed in SE16N, but when pulling this field in the RFC, I am given a value of "*17826100.000"

Any idea how to get the entire value to pull?

Comment: Give your `RFC_READ_TABLE` call code

Answer (score 2):

Don't use RFC_READ_TABLE... It has lots of limitations and shortcomings (in Unicode systems it may not work at all for certain tables) and also lots of security concerns.

Looks like you are running into one of these shortcomings here...

I would suggest to first check, whether there is already a standard SAP BAPI that reads from table MARD, and if there is none, then create your own remote enabled function module that does it. (And add an authorization check to your function module to protect the MARD data as necessary.)